# IN clause inside an update query, using JPQL

Tags: java, spring, jpql

i'm trying to execute this query:

```
    @Modifying
@Transactional
@Query(value = "UPDATE SpreadsheetRegisters r SET r.buApprobation =1 WHERE r.idRegister IN (:list)")
public void updateExpiredRegistries(@Param("list") List<BigDecimal> expiredRegistriesIds);
```

Basically, i'm trying to update a entity if her id is inside that list.

This is the exception i'm getting:

```
o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ORA-00936: missing expression

org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
```

It seems that my query is wrong, but i don't know where...
Anyone can help me ? 
thx

Comment: Can you show your entity SpreadsheetRegisters?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you guys for your support. After some hours i discovered the error. The query was right, but my list no, she was empty, and because of that the database couldn't do his work.

JPA: 1 
Me: 0

Answer (score 0):

Your entity class must be called “SpreadsheetRegisters” as you are using the query annotation. However, you can set the the native property of the @Query to be true if you want to use the database table name rather than the entity class name

It’s ok to keep the brackets, leave them.